# Unexpected token ] error during external json file call for cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use an external JSON file for creating graph in cytoscape.js. Goal is to get event based changes in graphs (i.e change in input data). For meeting that end, using external JSON files is what came to my mind.

Using the following call for fetching JSON contents:

```
var treeData;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      treeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/myfile.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

and supplying treeData to elements:

```
elements: treeData,
```

(I have tried without parsing the JSON as well).

Following is the structure of JSON file:

```
{
"nodes": [
  { "data": { "id": "j", "name": "Jerrymmmmmmm", "faveColor": "#6FB1FC", "size": 150} },
  { "data": { "id": "e", "name": "Elainemmmmmmm", "faveColor": "#EDA1ED", "size": 100 } },
  { "data": { "id": "k", "name": "Kramemmmmrmmm",  "faveColor": "#86B342", "size":90 } },
  { "data": { "id": "g", "name": "Georgemmmmmmm",  "faveColor": "#F5A45D", "size":75} },
   ],
"edges": [
  { "data": { "source": "j", "target": "e", "faveColor": "red",  } },
  { "data": { "source": "j", "target": "k", "faveColor": "red",} },
  { "data": { "source": "j", "target": "g", "faveColor": "black",} },
]
  }
```

Getting the following error:
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1449 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange.

Assistance highly appreciated...thanks

Comment: Your JSON is in valid. You have several trailing commas, eg. `..."faveColor": "black",} },`. You should remove them. You can check the validity of your JSON string at http://jsonlint.com

Comment: tried that as well..

Comment: Use the following page to validate your JSON and try your code again http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You might have tried it, but your json must have been still invalid. The error you get is because there is an issue in your JSON, usually a trailing comma, as @RoryMcCrossan said above. You should check that to solve your problem.

Comment: (Removed all trailing commas but to no avail...)
If I pass the contents of the JSON file to elements (as it is) the graph is generated...so is it that the data format taken by elements object doesn't conform with JSON structure?
Referring the elements object of this js and trying to validate it shoots error as well.
http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/b7c65115947d9e0e8ec8/code.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some extra commas in there buddy. After "red", after "black", after your last "nodes" object, and after your last "edges" object. Try this:

```
{
    "nodes": [{
        "data": {
            "id": "j",
            "name": "Jerrymmmmmmm",
            "faveColor": "#6FB1FC",
            "size": 150
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "e",
            "name": "Elainemmmmmmm",
            "faveColor": "#EDA1ED",
            "size": 100
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "k",
            "name": "Kramemmmmrmmm",
            "faveColor": "#86B342",
            "size": 90
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "g",
            "name": "Georgemmmmmmm",
            "faveColor": "#F5A45D",
            "size": 75
        }
    }],
    "edges": [{
        "data": {
            "source": "j",
            "target": "e",
            "faveColor": "red"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "j",
            "target": "k",
            "faveColor": "red"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "j",
            "target": "g",
            "faveColor": "black"
        }
    }]
}
```

Also, a very useful tool that can help you debug JSON errors is jsonlint: http://jsonlint.com/